# csrf security blocks http requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-post, csrf-protection

I want to use http post to post data from jsp page to my controller .the problem is  that when I enable csrf the request wasn't sent but I want to enable csrf can any one help me ?

home.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hello there !!!<br>
 <button type="button" onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create';"> start workflow</button> <br>
 <button type="button" onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/workflows';"> View Workflows</button> <br>
 <button type="button" onclick="sendDataWithJson();"> View data</button> <br>

<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">login</a>



    <p>Parameter from home  ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function success(data){
    alert("success");
}
function error(data){
    alert("error");
}
function sendDataWithJson(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<c:url value="/sendmessage" />',
    data: JSON.stringify({"text":"bla bla bla","name":"MED"}),
    success:success,
    error:error,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"

});

}


</script>
</html>
```

springsecurity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">


    <security:authentication-manager>
                <security:ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=users"
            group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})" group-search-base="ou=groups"
            group-role-attribute="cn" role-prefix="ROLE_" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:8389/o=mojo"
        manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret" />
    <security:http use-expressions="true">


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/next" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/workflows" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/getmessages" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/sendmessage" access="permitAll"/>


        <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
         login-processing-url="/login"
         authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"

          />
                <security:csrf/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/sendmessage" , method=RequestMethod.POST , produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getData(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data){
        String text=(String) data.get("text");
        String name=(String) data.get("name");
        System.out.println(text+","+name);
        Map<String, Object>rval = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        rval.put("success",true);
        return rval;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `csrf` value to html when you are using `jsp`:

```
<meta name="_csrf_param" content="${_csrf.parameterName}"/>
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

this will render the `crsf` value from session.

and now you are using `ajax`, you should add the `csrf` token in header, you can extend the `jquery`:

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```